# Best way to generate (and save) incremental invoice numbers in a multi-tenant MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, multi-tenant, invoice

I have found two different ways to, first, get the next invoice number and, then, save the invoice in a multi-tenant database where, of course, each tenant will have his own invoices with different incremental numbers.

- My **first (and actual) approach** is this (works fine):

1. Add a new record to the invoices tables. No matter the invoice number yet (for example, 0, or empty)
2. I get the unique ID of THAT created record after insert
3. Now I do a `"SELECT table where ID = $lastcreatedID **FOR UPDATE**"`
4. Here I get the latest saved invoice number with `"SELECT @A:=MAX(NUMBER)+1 FROM TABLE WHERE......"`
5. Finally I update the previously saved record with that invoice number with an `"UPDATE table SET NUMBER = $mynumber WHERE ID = $lastcreatedID"`

This works fine, but I don't know if the "for update" is really needed or if this is the correct way to do this in a multi-tenant DB, due to performance, etc.

- **The second (and simpler) approach** is this (and works too, but I don't know if it is a *secure* approach):

1. `INSERT INTO table (NUMBER,TENANT) SELECT COALESCE(MAX(NUMBER),0)+1,$tenant FROM table WHERE....`
2. That's it

Both methods are working, but I would like to know the differences between them regarding speed, performance, if it may create duplicates, etc.

Or... is there any better way to do this?

I'm using MySQL and PHP. The application is an invoice/sales cloud software that will be used by a lot of customers (tenants).

Thanks

Comment: "Ok I added an invoice. Oops, there was some bad info, so I deleted it. Ok I made a new invoice with the right info. Wait, it has the same invoice number as the last one? And there's a bunch of bad metadata from the previous broken invoice? Oh no parts of the app are just straight-up broken..." This is what awaits you when you assign IDs with `MAX()+1`. There's an extra layer of bad when you consider that this is multi-tenant and there's a good chance that a completely different tenant is going to get hit with the bug.

Comment: I don't assign IDs with MAX+1. I assign invoice numbers. That's not an ID. You shouldn't delete an invoice. You must  (at least in Spain) create a new one rectifying the bad one. In any case... if you delete an invoice, the next invoice number will be max (invoice) + 1. Again, I think you confused ID (unique for each record) with Invoice Number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of if you're using these values as database IDs or not, re-using IDs is virtually guaranteed to cause problems at some point. Even if you're not re-using IDs you're going to run into the case where two invoice creation requests run at the same time and get the same `MAX()+1` result.

To get around all this you need to reimplement a simple sequence generator that locks its storage while a value is being issued. Eg:

```sql
CREATE TABLE client_invoice_serial (
  -- note: also FK this back to the client record
  client_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  serial INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

```php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:...');
/* this defaults to 'on', making every query an implicit transaction. it needs to
be off for this. you may or may not want to set this globally, or just turn it off
before this, and back on at the end. */
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT,0);
// simple best practice, ensures that SQL errors MUST be dealt with. is assumed to be enabled for the below try/catch.
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,1);

$dbh->beginTransaction();
try {
    // the below will lock the selected row
    $select = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM client_invoice_serial WHERE client_id = ? FOR UPDATE;");
    $select->execute([$client_id]);

    if( $select->rowCount() === 0 ) {
        $insert = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO client_invoice_serial (client_id, serial) VALUES (?, 1);");
        $insert->execute([$client_id]);
        $invoice_id = 1;
    } else {
        $invoice_id = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['serial'] + 1;
        $update = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE client_invoice_serial SET serial = serial + 1 WHERE client_id = ?");
        $update->execute([$client_id])
    }
    $dbh->commit();
} catch(\PDOException $e) {
    // make sure that the transaction is cleaned up ASAP, then let the exception bubble up into your general error handling.
    $dbh->rollback();
    throw $e; // or throw a more pertinent error/exception of your choosing.
}
// both committing and rolling back will release the lock
```

At a very basic level this is what MySQL is doing in the background for AUTOINCREMENT columns.

Comment: Thanks, @Sammitch. So it seems the first approach (using "for update") within a transaction is the best way to achieve this. I'm using mysqli_ instead of PDO, so I'm afraid I need to change some things.

Comment: All the PDO calls should have MySQLi equivalents and, as you said, the real magic is in the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE; INSERT/UPDATE` in a transaction. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you allow users to modify your auto generated number, you might want to use a hybrid approach.  Select both the max previous reference number, and the max existing row id (auto incremented unique column).  Then compare to see which is the lowest, add 1, and use that as your new reference number.

In this example the reference number column is a varchar so I'm also using a regexp to remove any non numeric characters from the reference number before doing the comparison.

```
  $db->query("select max(t.id) maxid,max(cast(t.reference as unsigned)) maxreference
                  from transactions t
                 where t.companyid = :companyid
                   and transactiontype = 'C'
                   and t.reference REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'");
  $db->bind(":companyid",$companyid);

  if ($row = $db->single()){
    $maxreference = $row["maxreference"];
    $maxid = $row["maxid"];
    if($maxreference <> ''){
      // Get lower of two numbers
      $number = min($maxreference, $maxid);

      // Make sure it is at least 4 characters long
      $number = str_pad($number + 1,4,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }else{
      // If max reference # is blank, start with 0001
      $number = "0001";
    }
  }else{
    // If no row is found, start with 0001
    $number = "0001";
  }
```

The advantage of this approach is that the user can start with lower 4 digit numbers (even if you already have millions of rows), but if they inadvertently enter in a huge number manually to use as their reference number, the next auto generated number will not use that but will instead use the max row id, which is smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Do *not* use `MAX(id)+1`.  It will, someday, bite you.  There will be two invoices with the same number, and it will take us a few paragraphs to explain why it happened.

Instead, use `AUTO_INCREMENT` the way it is intended.

```
INSERT INTO Invoices (id, ...) VALUES (NULL, ...);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();   -- specific to the conne ction
```

That is safe even when multiple connections are doing the same thing.  No `FOR UPDATE`, no  `BEGIN`, etc is necessary.  (You may want such for other purposes.)

And, *never* delete rows.  Instead, use the standard business practice of invalidating bad invoices.  Imagine being audited.

All that said, there is still a potential problem.  After a `ROLLBACK` or system crash, an id may be "burned".  Also things like `INSERT IGNORE` allocate the id before checking to see whether it will be needed.

If you can live with the caveats, use `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

If not, then create a 1-row, 2-column table to simulate a sequence number generator:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#sequence

Or use MariaDB's `SEQUENCE`

Comment: As I understand it the issue is that this is something like a SaaS billing system. There's a single `Invoice` table containing invoices generated by multiple SaaS user entities, and what OP seemingly wants is for each SaaS user to have sequential invoice IDs. I'm curious if you have any thoughts on the solution I posted. [Also TIL mariadb has sequence generators now]

Comment: @Sammitch - Unexpected gaps; rollback; crash; atomicity of fetching new number vs storing it.  Did you want separate numbers for each tenant or one sequence for all?  Performance is not likely to be an issue.  Is replication/clustering involved?  Etc.

Comment: Enclosing the ID generation in a transaction + `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` should address that initial crop of concerns. The other questions are best directed to OP for clarification, but my assumption is that OP wants each user to have their own sequence for invoice IDs.

Answer (score -1):

Both the approaches do work, but each with its own demerits in high traffic situations.

The first approach runs 3 queries for every invoice you create, putting extra load on your server.

The second approach can lead to duplicates in events where two invoices are generated with very little time difference (such that the SELECT query return same max number for both invoices).

Both the approaches may lead to problems in high traffic conditions.

Two solutions to the problems are listed below:

1. **Use generated columns**: Mysql supports generated columns, which are basically derived using other column values for each row. Refer [this](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-generated-columns)
2. **Calculate invoice number on the fly**: Since you're using the primary key as part of the invoice, let the DB handle generating unique primary keys, and then generate invoice numbers on the fly in your business logic using the id for each invoice.

Comment: Hi, @Aayush. Does a generated column allow using 'max()' to get the last invoice number for THAT tenant? Remember that the NUMBER column is not the ID (unique) column.